# (select) elements still taking space after display:none

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

So the problem is that for any other elements, display:none make the element invisible and doesn't take up space, however only for the  element, it still take up space when display:none.

```
<style>
#test { display:none; }
</style>

<body>
<select id='test'>
<option value='option1'>option1</option>
<option value='option2'>option2</option>
</select>
</body>
```

It just made the select element invisible, but still takes up space, I tried giving display:none to the option elements too, and have researched on google and stackoverflow, but it seems nobody is getting the same problem. Anybody could shed some light about this?
Thankyou in advance.

Comment: Can you reproduce the problem? I can't!

Comment: try to give it position: absolute;

Comment: it is fine - http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/ptbsfu4q/1/ - unless you can help reproduce it we won't be able to offer much help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Works perfectly fine. Here's a side-by-side example:

With the `<select>` hidden using `display: none`:

```css
#test { display:none; }
```

```html
<select id='test'>
<option value='option1'>option1</option>
<option value='option2'>option2</option>
</select>
<p>Lorem Ipsum Dolor Ismet. Lorem Ipsum Dolor Ismet. Lorem Ipsum Dolor Ismet. Lorem Ipsum Dolor Ismet. Lorem Ipsum Dolor Ismet. Lorem Ipsum Dolor Ismet. Lorem Ipsum Dolor Ismet. Lorem Ipsum Dolor Ismet. Lorem Ipsum Dolor Ismet. Lorem Ipsum Dolor Ismet. Lorem Ipsum Dolor Ismet. </p>
```

With the `<select>` visible:

```html
<select id='test'>
  <option value='option1'>option1</option>
  <option value='option2'>option2</option>
</select>
<p>Lorem Ipsum Dolor Ismet. Lorem Ipsum Dolor Ismet. Lorem Ipsum Dolor Ismet. Lorem Ipsum Dolor Ismet. Lorem Ipsum Dolor Ismet. Lorem Ipsum Dolor Ismet. Lorem Ipsum Dolor Ismet. Lorem Ipsum Dolor Ismet. Lorem Ipsum Dolor Ismet. Lorem Ipsum Dolor Ismet. Lorem
  Ipsum Dolor Ismet.</p>
```

The problem about which you've mentioned can only occur if you set the `visibility` of `<select>` to `hidden`, like this:

```css
#test { visibility: hidden; }
```

```html
<select id='test'>
<option value='option1'>option1</option>
<option value='option2'>option2</option>
</select>
<p>Lorem Ipsum Dolor Ismet. Lorem Ipsum Dolor Ismet. Lorem Ipsum Dolor Ismet. Lorem Ipsum Dolor Ismet. Lorem Ipsum Dolor Ismet. Lorem Ipsum Dolor Ismet. Lorem Ipsum Dolor Ismet. Lorem Ipsum Dolor Ismet. Lorem Ipsum Dolor Ismet. Lorem Ipsum Dolor Ismet. Lorem Ipsum Dolor Ismet. </p>
```

There might be some other element which is hidden using `visibility: hidden` or an element with some sort of a `margin`.

Comment: ok, so turns out the gap is caused by a br element in between, stupid newbie mistake. I was trying to make the elements to display none and block, any chance it could be achieved ? Thank you very much for your help.

Comment: you can also define `br{display:none;}`